# User log in with ASP.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, authorization

First time trying to deal with users logging in with ASP.net and haven't had much experience with it with other things. From searching, I am seeing things like Asp.Net MVC Membership Provider. Is this a built in thing?

Is there any good online guides for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at **[the ASP.NET Provider Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479020.aspx)**. The MembershipProvider is a provider in the built-in provider model for handling users and you can [download the source code of the default providers](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/13/442772.aspx) to look at how they are implemented.

If you want to install the default provider databases on a sql server, you can run [Aspnet_regsql.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229862%28VS.80%29.aspx) from the command line to do so.

The great thing about the provider model is that it is very straightforward to write your own providers by deriving from the abstract base classes and use them in an application. You need only implement the methods that you need.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial that walk you through creating the required database schema in sql express, it also explains what you need to do to move to other sql data sources.  It explains how to setup users in forms authentication mode so that you can use role based authorization etc

http://www.asp.net/learn/moving-to-asp.net-2.0/module-08.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ASP.NET membership features with MVC if you'd like.  Are you wanting to use it with MVC or not?  [Scott Mitchell](https://web.archive.org/web/20210513220018/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) has a great tutorial that has several parts teaching many of the things one would want to know to get a website up and running.  The built in Membership works well for basic situations but can become a pain as one wants to start adding more information to the user's profile.

Comment: Well the default MVC Site template in Visual Studio has an example log in page, etc. that leverages the Membership capabilities including a log in screen, etc.  Using that plus the tutorials I linked should get you most of the way there.

Comment: Anyone else think the 4 guys from rolla are sort of ... bad developers?